# d3.js axis height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

```
var vis = d3.select("#visualisation");
xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
        .ticks(numberOfRecords);

vis.append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("height", 30)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
```

hi guys,
since i updated from d3.js version 3.5 to 4.2.1 the thickness of my x-axis is wrong.
with the version 3.5 i could just set the height but it is not working anymore.
any ideas?
thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? Is it too thin or too thick? Besides that, I'm not sure that "height" here has any effect.

Comment: i want it to be thicker. the code worked with the 3.5 version.

Comment: Using CSS, select `.axis path, .axis line` and set the stroke width.